# Reference for infinite horizon constrained Markov decision process

Tags: references, markov-process, constraint, linear-programming

I am looking for some introductions or reviews material for solving  infinite horizon constrained Markov decision process. The book I am reading upon is constrained Markov decision process by Eitan Altman. It would be great if there are any introductory level materials are recommended. Any suggestions?